# php fputscv not creating csv file instead showing output on same page

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

On my local machine it is working fine. but on server it is printing the output on the same page instead of creating of a CSV file. can anyone help

```
// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed

header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=memberList.csv');

ob_end_clean();

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('First Name', 'Last Nameenter code here', 'Street Name', 'City', 'State', 'Zip Code'));

// fetch the data
$csvQry  = "SELECT * from tabel where num=1";

if ($_POST['stateList']!='all'){
    $csvQry  = "SELECT * from table";
}

$csvRows = mysqli_query($db,$csvQry);

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($csvRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($csvRows)) {
   fputcsv($output, $csvRow);
}

fclose($output);
```

Comment: Well, looks like a problem with your headers. Do you have any error messages?

Comment: Wait, you are writing to `php://output` why would you expect it to write to a file?

Comment: @dan08 the code is working fine locally and it was working fine before on another hosting too i.e. Csv file getting created fine. But now on new hosting, the same code is not generating the csv file, instead writing the output on the page.

Comment: @Paul no errors.. Just plain output in comma separated format on the page and no csv file. I wonder if some setting i need to change on apche or php side.

Comment: are you getting the results of your query in your output, or is it just echoing elements of the page?